# How to get started with oracle sql developer. How to solve the adapter error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-connection

[image]

Having program while starting up with oracle sql developer[image]

How to proceed

These are the connection properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your connection properties in SQL Developer are probably not correct. Examine the connection properties and make sure you can reach the machine oracle is running on via PING. If you can, ensure the database is indeed open and being serviced by the listener on the port defined in the connection as well.

I talk about diagnosing connection issues [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/30-sql-developer-tips-in-30-days-day-5-connectivity-issues/).

I talk about how to get started [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/).

Comment: I am so poor in db and networks i can not figure out

Comment: right-click on the connection in SQL Developer, go to properties. take a screenshot, and show us what you have.

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith

Comment: Read this - http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/

you're trying to connect to an oracle database on your computer. Do you remember installing Oracle and creating a database? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: oracle 11g xe n oracle sql developer are enough rite?

Comment: yes, if you installed XE and have SQLDev, you're good to go. make sure XE is actually running. On windows, you should have a service.